# Marshalling java object to XML in different format?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xstream

I have below xml

```
<note>
<to>Tony</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

i have  constructed Note.java (data object) from it on which i do some validation

Now i want to construct  XML in below format from Note.java.

One way i can think of is  create MyCustomNote.java(another data  object). Map fields of note.java to MyCustomNote.java.
Then construct xml in below format with tools like xstream or jaxb. But i am not sure its the right or some better way is there?

```
<MyCustomNote>
<toAddress>Tony</toAddress>
<fromName>Jani</fromName>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<output>someOutput</output>
</MyCustomNote>
```

**UPDATE :-**

Note.java is

```
public Class Note {

private String to;
private String from;
private String heading;
private String body;

//getters and setters for each the above field

}
```

Comment: The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so with xstream will be simple:

```
final XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
xstream.alias("MyCustomNote", Note.class);
xstream.aliasField("toAddress", Note.class,"to");
xstream.aliasField("fromName", Note.class,"from");
xstream.aliasField("heading", Note.class,"heading");
xstream.aliasField("output", Note.class,"body");
```

that will be in main(), in Note.java you will have to set @Field on getMethods().
also would be great to post your Note.java too

**UPDATE:**

ExportToXml.class

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxDriver;

public class ExportToXml {

public Note createNote() {

    Note container = new Note();
    container.setBody("Don't forget me this weekend!");
    container.setFrom("Jeni");
    container.setHeading("Reminder");
    container.setTo("Tony");

    return container;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    final XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.alias("MyCustomNote", Note.class);
    xstream.aliasField("toAddress", Note.class,"to");
    xstream.aliasField("fromName", Note.class,"from");
    xstream.aliasField("heading", Note.class,"heading");
    xstream.aliasField("output", Note.class,"body");

    ExportToXml export = new ExportToXml();

    Note firstNote = export.createNote();

    final File file = new File("D:\\export.xml");
    BufferedOutputStream stdout;
    try {

        stdout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    xstream.marshal(firstNote, new PrettyPrintWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(stdout)));

}
```

}

Note.class

```
 public class Note {

private String to;
private String from;
private String heading;
private String body;

public String getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public String getHeading() {
    return heading;
}

public void setHeading(String heading) {
    this.heading = heading;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}
```

the result will be export.xml

```
  <MyCustomNote>
    <toAddress>Tony</toAddress>
    <fromName>Jeni</fromName>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <output>Don't forget me this weekend!</output>
  </MyCustomNote>
```

Comment: @ Iulian Alexandru Costeiu. Posted Note.java under my update section. I am not sure what do you mean by "in Note.java you will have to set @Field on getMethods()". Can you give small example?

Comment: try without @Field annotation, it's supposed to run